# How to group by a column and do normalization?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dateframe like this:

```
    A      B      C       
0  foo    one     1
1  bar    one     2
2  foo    two     1
3  bar  three     2
4  foo    two     3
5  bar    two     5
6  foo    one     2
7  foo  three     5
8  bar    one     4
```

I want to group by 'B' and do normalization on 'C' column foreach particular 'B'.
I'd like to do a simple min-max norm like x / max(x)

```
grouped_b = df.groupby('B')

def norm(value):
    return value/value.max()

norm_B = grouped_b['C'].agg(norm)
```

The result would looks like this:

```
    A      B      C       
0  foo    one    0.25
1  bar    one    0.5
2  foo    two    0.2
3  bar  three    0.25
4  foo    two    0.6
5  bar    two     1
6  foo    one    0.5
7  foo  three     1
8  bar    one     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original `df`:

```
grouped_b = df.groupby('B')

def norm(value):
    return value/value.max()

df['C'] = grouped_b['C'].transform(norm)

print (df)
     A      B     C
0  foo    one  0.25
1  bar    one  0.50
2  foo    two  0.20
3  bar  three  0.40
4  foo    two  0.60
5  bar    two  1.00
6  foo    one  0.50
7  foo  three  1.00
8  bar    one  1.00
```

You can also use `lambda` function:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['C'].transform(lambda x: x / x.max())
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `transform`

```
df.C/=df.groupby(['B']).C.transform('max')
```